# Making junit test case for interactor/presenter in android(kotlin) using mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito

In my application i am following MVP pattern, in this i want to make junit test cases for presenter and model(interactor) classes to validate the business logic.

Below is the code i have written for presenter and model, and i also also written a junit test case as mentioned below.

**LoginPresenterImpl.kt**

```
class LoginPresenterImpl : LoginPresenter, LoginResponseCallback {


lateinit var loginIntegractor:LoginIntegractor
override fun loginSuccess(user: User) {
    loginView.hidProgress()
    loginView.loginSuucces(user)

}

override fun loginFailed(errorMessage: String) {
    loginView.hidProgress()
    loginView.loginFailed(errorMessage)

}

lateinit var loginView:LoginView
constructor(context: Context,loginView: LoginView){
    this.loginView = loginView;
    loginIntegractor = LoginInteractorImpl(context,this);
}
override fun login(userName: String, password: String) {
    loginView.showProgress();
    loginIntegractor.login(userName,password);
}
}
```

**LoginInteractorImpl.kt** This file consist of business logic of login

```
class LoginInteractorImpl : LoginIntegractor {

val  TAG:String = LoginInteractorImpl::class.java.simpleName;
var loginResponseCallback: LoginResponseCallback;
var context: Context? = null;

constructor(context: Context,loginResponseCallback: LoginResponseCallback){
    this.context = context;
    this.loginResponseCallback = loginResponseCallback;
}
constructor(loginResponseCallback: LoginResponseCallback){
    this.loginResponseCallback = loginResponseCallback;
}

override fun login(username: String, password: String) {
    if(username.trim().isBlank()){
        loginResponseCallback.loginFailed("Please enter username");
    }
    else if(password.trim().isBlank()){
        loginResponseCallback.loginFailed("Please enter password");
    }
    else{

        val apiService:ApiService = ApiService.Factory.create();
        val jsonObject = JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("username",username);
        jsonObject.put("password",password);
        val call:Call<LoginResponse> = apiService.login(jsonObject.toString())
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
                Log.d(TAG, "login success")
                if (response != null) {
                    val status = response.body()!!.getStatus()
                    if (status == 0) {
                        loginResponseCallback.loginSuccess(response.body()!!.getUser())
                    } else {
                        loginResponseCallback.loginFailed(response.body()!!.getMessage())
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "login failed")
                loginResponseCallback.loginFailed("Something went wrong while login")
            }
        })
    }

}
```

}

**LoginInteractorTest.kt** This is juit test case file.

```
class LoginInteractorTest {

var loginIntegractor:LoginIntegractor? = null
@Mock
private lateinit var callback: LoginResponseCallback
@Captor
private lateinit var argumentCaptor:ArgumentCaptor<LoginResponseCallback>;
@Captor
private lateinit var nameCapcture:ArgumentCaptor<String>;
@Captor
private lateinit var pwdcapcture:ArgumentCaptor<String>;
private lateinit var user: User;
@Before
fun setUp(){
    callback = mock()
    user = mock()
    val captor = argumentCaptor<() -> Unit>()
    nameCapcture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String::class.java)
    pwdcapcture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String::class.java)
    loginIntegractor = LoginInteractorImpl(callback)
}

@Test
fun testLogin() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    loginIntegractor?.login("ashok","narra")
   // verify(loginIntegractor?.login(nameCapcture.capture(),pwdcapcture.capture()))
   // argumentCaptor.value.loginSuccess(ArgumentMatchers.any(User::class.java))
    Mockito.verify(callback).loginSuccess(ArgumentMatchers.any(User::class.java));
}
```

}

test case fails **saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArgumentMatchers.any(User::class.java) must not be null". Can anyone suggest how to we implement junit test cases for presenter/model classes in android using kotlin?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and to be honest I couldn't solve it and ended up using [`mockito-kotlin`](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin).

Instead of

```
 Mockito.verify(callback).loginSuccess(ArgumentMatchers.any(User::class.java));
```

You can simply write:

```
Mockito.verify(callback).loginSuccess(any())
```

Where `any()` comes from mockito kotlin. There's usually no need to specify the type, but in case you need it you can always do it like `any<User>()`

Comment: I have tried , but it still give error as below.

"Wanted but not invoked:
callback.loginSuccess(
    <any xxx.xxx.User>
);
-> at xxx.xxx.LoginInteractorTest.testLogin(LoginInteractorTest.kt:46)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock."

Comment: that's just the test failing. In other words, it tells you that the code is not actually calling `loginSuccess` with any argument. You need to debug it and figure out what's wrong. However, as far as mockito goes everything seems ok